# After Click an approve button, the Item status did not change in laravel 5.4

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, laravel

Good day guys, I having a problem on change the item status by just click the approve button..

This is my blade and my script for ajax:

```
<tbody>
        @foreach($donation as $donation)
        <br>
        <br>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $donation->DonationId }}</td>
                <td>{{ $donation->AttrName }}</td>
                <td>{{ $donation->AttrType }}</td>
                <td>{{ $donation->AttrSize }}</td>
                <td>{{ $donation->ItemImage }}</td>
                <td>{{ $donation->ItemQuantity }}</td>
                <td>{{ $donation-> DonationDate }}</td>
                <td>{{ $donation->DeliveryType }}</td>
                <td>{{ $donation-> DonationStatus }}</td>
                <td>
                    <button data-id="{{$donation->DonationDetailsId}}" data-name="{{$donation->DonationStatus}}" id="approved">Approve</button>


</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

<script>
    $("$approved").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url:  '/viewDonation/approve',
            da 
        @endforeach
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>ta:{
                'id': $('#theId').val($(this).data('DonationDetailsId')),
                'name': $('#na').val("Approved") 

            },
            success: function(data){
                    $('.item'+ data.id).replacewith("<tr><td>"+ data.name + "</td></tr>")
            }
        })
    })

</script>
```

And This is my Controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
   $data = DonationDetails::find($request->DonationDetailsId);
   $data->DonationStatus="Approved";
   $data->save();
   return response()->json($data);

}
```

and this is my route:

```
Route::post('/viewDonation/approve','ViewDonationController@update');
```

Can you please help me how to change is status. Because after I click the Approve button the Item Status did not change at the data base. Thanks!

Comment: Please fix your codes first, there is foreach inside your ajax.

Comment: Sorry I paste a wrong Code. this is my updated code.                      
 `<script type="text/javascript">
    $("$approved").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url:  '/viewDonation/approve',
           data:{
                'id': $('#theId').val($(this).data('DonationDetailsId')),
                'name': $('#na').val("Approved") 
            },
            success: function(data){
                    $('.item'+ data.id).replacewith("<tr><td>"+ data.name + "</td></tr>")
            }
        });
    });
</script>`